# Whats the relationship between Pascal's triangle and Combination

Tags: algebra-precalculus, combinations, binomial-coefficients

I've been taught all the normal stuff about combinations and the usage of combinations in the formulas, but we were never told why they are used, and why they work.
I tried looking it up, but the only answer I was able to find was behind a paywall
I'm sorry if I didn't provide many details. I'm new here.

Comment: This seems awfully broad.  Can you give a more specific instance of something you don't understand?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what to say. I just don't understand why combinations are used or why they work in binomial theorem question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combinations are used for counting.  If I have a bin with $8$ balls numbered $1$ through $8$ and I draw $3$ of them, how many different outcomes are possible?  Here we are only concerned with which balls we end up with, not the order we drew them in, and the answer is $\binom 83$ which you may have see written in your course as $C(8,3)$ or $_8C_3$ or $C^8_3$ or something similar.

Now suppose I want to multiply out $(a+x)^8$.  How do we do this?  We have
$$\underbrace{(a+x)(a+x)\cdots(a+x)}_{n \text{ factors}}$$  We choose one term from each factor, multiply them out, and add up the products over all choices of terms.

Now what is the coefficient of $x^3$?  The only way to get a product involves $x^3$ is to choose $3$ $x$'s and $5$ $a$'s, so the product will be always be $a^5x^3$, but how many products are there?  How many ways are there to choose $3$ $x$'s from $8$ possibilities?  It's $\binom{8}{3}$ as above.  If you don't immediately see the relation between this problem and the balls in the bin, think of choosing balls $3,5,6$ as choosing the $x$ from factor numbers $3,5,6$ and choosing $a$ from the other factors.

Of course, this works for for any power of $x$, not just $3$, and I hope it explains the use of combinations in the binomial theorem to you.

Comment: Woah cool! thanks for the explanation!